# Use dynamic import in vue router with laravel mix

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack

I use laravel 5.7 with Vue 2.5 and VueRouter 3.0 .

I want to use dynamic modules ([see here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html)).

This is my `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": [
        ["env", {
            "modules": false,
            "targets": {
                "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
            }
        }],
        "stage-2"
    ],
    "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-runtime","syntax-dynamic-import","dynamic-import-node"],
    "env": {
        "test": {
            "presets": ["env", "stage-2","es2015"],
            "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs", "syntax-dynamic-import"]
        }
    }
}
```

And my `webpack.mix.js`:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.webpackConfig({
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.styl$/,
                loader: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'stylus-loader'],
            }
        ],
    }
});

mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            "@": path.resolve(
                __dirname,
                "resources/js"
            )
        }
    }
});

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css');
```

And my routes, with dynamic import :

```
export default [
  {
    path: '/404',
    meta: {
      public: true,
    },
    name: 'NotFound',
    component: () => import(
      /* webpackChunkName: "routes" */
      /* webpackMode: "lazy-once" */
      `@/pages/NotFound.vue`
    )
  },
]
```

But when I access in my app, my `NotFound` module is not find :

```
 Error: "Cannot find module 'function () {
        return require('@/pages/NotFound.vue');
      }'."
```

I can give more code or explain if you want.

My goal, it's to integrate [vue-material-admin](https://github.com/tookit/vue-material-admin) with Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Ok right, my `.babelrc`was wrong.

This is right file :

```
{
    "presets": [
        "stage-2"
    ],
    "plugins": ["transform-vue-jsx", "transform-runtime","syntax-dynamic-import"]
}
```

I don't feel comfortable with Webpack and Babel, so I accept explanation.